# How do I make a round hay roof?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to learn modeling so I'm pretty new to it. How can I make this hay roof?

[image]

Comment: i tried using a circle, extruding it some times and merging it at the top but it looks too simple.

Comment: i would like to make it look less perfect. make it look more natural like it was made by humans

Comment: Use hair particles to make the straws

Comment: i have no clue how to use the hair particle. i want to add that AND make the circle have some imperfections so it doesnt look like something perfect.

Comment: ill check some tutorials for the hair particle. but i still need help with imperfecting the circle

Comment: look also for tutorials on proportional editing

Comment: anyways i fixed it

Answer (score 23):

### Image as reference, proportional editing/sculpting, and tip thickness

As you have a reference image, I think the best way to start the modeling is blocking out of the shape right onto the reference image to ensure the similarity of the proportions.

Keep the topology tidy in this phase as long as possible. In my test file I started by *extruding* and *scaling* a circle on the Z-axis while keeping an *image-type empty* behind. Don't worry about the a-symmetry of the reference object, just focus on the overall proportions.

For the tip I went for a *grid fill*, followed by some *smooth vertex* operator iterations.

[image]

The shape has now some kind of radial symmetry that we would like to avoid. I took advantage of the *proportional editing* tool to *grab* the vertices around and various *sculpt* tools to smooth the shape (or to bump out some parts).

[image] [image]

Add to the roof a *hair particle system*, set the right amount of particles, *comb* the hairs toward the bottom (in *particle edit* mode) and use *weight paint* to adjust the density and length.

[image]

Once satisfied with the distribution, start tweaking the parameters of the individual hairs. I went for a long stick type by setting the *Tip* section equal to the *Root* section. You can find more info about how to control the shape of the strand in the [Blender Manual page](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/strands.html):

[image]

[image]

Finish by setting the *Children* particles type to one of the proposed modes (in this case I went for *Interpolated*) to increase the amount of particles.

Play with other parameters till you reach the right look for your job. Here's a possible result:

[image]

*Note: this is just a presentation of the workflow and the tools I would use for the job. Each one probably requires some time and further research in order to be mastered.*

[image]